# SQL Server : INSERT INTO SELECT doesn't insert into the correct column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 to try to take the values of one column in a table and put them into the values of another column table in another. If I try to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column3)
    SELECT column3
    FROM table1
    WHERE (ScopeID IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY Name
```

For `table2`, `column3` is the same type (an `int`), `NULL` values are allowed. But when I try to execute the query, it returns:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'column1', table 'dbo.table2';, column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

But I'm not trying to insert into `column1`... Is it just a syntax thing where the order of the columns HAVE to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* inserting into `column1`.  Remember, you are inserting entire *rows* of values, so you should really have a value for all columns.  Your query is equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3)
    SELECT NULL, NULL, column3
    FROM table1
    WHERE (ScopeID IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY Name;
```

(and so on for all the columns in the table.)

I am guessing that you actually want an `update`, but your question doesn't provide enough information to give further guidance.

Comment: Ah, yes, `update` is probably what I should have done. Thank you, although this isn't a direct answer it helped lead me in the direction of where I needed to go!